# what's the difference in Chrome's incognito and Normal window?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, hyperlink

Is it possible to call an incognito window in an application. I am using Unity3D to make a PC game and I used code to call/ open a my FB page using:

```
Application.OpenUrl("www.facebook.com/username")
```

This opens the default browser's window but in normal window.
Should there be something in my link that says it is incognito.

Comment: I want it to be incognito because I don't want to burden the user to save history about another fb account just open it.

Comment: The first part of the question should go into another site (maybe Super User?). I've edited it out. For the second part, can you show something else you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incognito uses a new set of cookies, not the ones in the normal window. That is why you can login to two facebook accounts, facebook tracks you by your cookies.

Chrome has a parameter --incognito to open in incognito.

```
C:\path\to\chrome.exe --incognito http://facebook.com/username
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast Answer Justice I will try and use your suggestion.

Comment: It worked! I cant Believe it is just simple as this. Thanks :) Accepted your answer.